# Elapsed time counting

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, cron

I have a small script (basically very easy this is the first I wrote) and likes to know the elapsed time, how long it takes when it is finished.

Is it possible to count the difference between the two variable? ($SSS and $EEE), I did try with the $SECONDS as well but it gives 0 as a result.

Probably a different way needs to be used to make this work, so I need need regarding how can I solve this.

My script:

```bsh
echo "****************************************************************************"
SECONDS=0
#!/bin/bash
SSS=$(date '+%Y.%m.%d. @ %H:%M:%S')
echo "Start time: ${SSS}"
echo ""
echo "Starting update and upgrade"
echo "==================================="
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
echo ""
echo "Starting autoremove"
echo "==================================="
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
echo ""
echo "Starting autoclean"
echo "==================================="
sudo apt-get autoclean -y
echo ""
echo "Check for Pi-Hole update"
echo "==================================="
sudo pihole -up
echo ""
echo "Starting gravity update for Pi-Hole"
echo "==================================="
sudo pihole -g
echo ""
EEE=$(date '+%Y.%m.%d. @ %H:%M:%S')
echo "Start time: ${SSS}"
echo "End   time: ${EEE}"
duration=$SECONDS
echo "Elapsed time $(($duration / 60)) minutes and $(($duration % 60)) seconds."
echo "****************************************************************************"
```

Comment: What is the code that you have in the "magic" section? If I put something like `sleep 3` there and run your script, I get `3` as output for `$SECONDS` and your final `echo` seems to give me the correct values.  Do you need subsecond resolution? Did you, in that case, try using `$EPOCHREALTIME`?

Comment: also, `/usr/bin/time` probably does what you want, already, if "magic" happens to be running an executable!

Comment: You can also assign `date +s` (the seconds since Jan 1st, 1970) to SSS and EEE and perform a simple subtraction.

Comment: Thank you all of the answer, did some further test and it looks like if I just run the script ./myscript.sh it works fine Start time: 2021.05.02. @ 15:09:54
End   time: 2021.05.02. @ 15:16:59
Elapsed time 7 minutes and 5 seconds.   but if I use crontab then it gives me the following Start time: 2021.05.02. @ 15:22:01
End   time: 2021.05.02. @ 15:28:17
Elapsed time 0 minutes and 0 seconds. What can be the issue is?

Comment: since this is on a debian-based machine, and all sensible distros that are debian based supported this for years: your script in crontab is redundant. You can configure automatic updates, systemd will keep timers to make sure they're run, and `systemctl status` / `journalctl` will tell you how long updates took. In fact, writing something in crontab in 2021 is really just an awkward way to achieve the initiation of a timer unit in systemd. https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your script has nothing to do with the timing of the commands.  The issue with your script is that it is running in an environment which is different to the environment you run it in from your command line.

For example, the `PATH` variable may be different leading to some utilities not being found, or there are interactive elements to the script that obviously can't be carried out when the script is running in a non-interactive environment.

You also mention [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647692/elapsed-time-counting/647732?noredirect=1#comment1214285_647732) that you start the script using `sh` rather than `bash`, which additionally means that the `SECONDS` variable may not exist (depending on what shell `sh` happens to be implemented by).

I can see that the script executes almost every single command using `sudo`.  This leads me to suggest that you should be running the script in root's own crontab and not in the crontab of a non-privileged user account (and remove all the `sudo` invocations from the script).  Modify the root user's crontab using `sudo crontab -e`.

Furthermore, make sure that the `PATH` variable in the script is set to a list of directories that allows you to find all the utilities that you use.  For example,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

SECONDS=0

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

# etc.
```

You should in particular make sure that the `PATH` variable contains the directories where `apt-get` and `pihole` lives (find these with `command -v pihole` and `command -v apt-get` on the command line).

Also make sure that the `#!`-line is the first line of the file (as I've shown here in my example).  The code in the question is not doing this.  Note that the `#!`-line *is completely ignored* if you use an explicit interpreter on the command line when invoking the script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I made some modifications, I wrote absolute path to run every command and crontab run with root, however issue still remains. What needs to be modified? https://pastebin.pl/view/6eab625d Thank you!

Comment: @RamboJunior When you look at the output of the script, are there errors? Are you logging both the standard output stream and the standard error stream to a file somewhere?  Is the script _supposed_ to take a long time to run (if there are no updates, for example)?

Comment: No errors runs smoothly, here is the output:  https://pastebin.com/JYBpwTs3 in crontab I use the 2>&1 so the standard output. It usually takes about 7 minutes to complete. Crontab line looks like this: 5 8 * * 1  sh /home/pi/update.sh 2>&1 >>  /home/pi/logs/cronlog

Comment: @RamboJunior Why are you running it with `sh` and not with `bash`? If your `sh` is `dash`, then it has no `SECONDS` variable.

Comment: BANG Start time: 2021.05.03. @ 10:30:01
End   time: 2021.05.03. @ 10:36:33
Elapsed time 6 minutes and 32 seconds. Thank you very much for your help, all sorted :)

Comment: @RamboJunior Good!  I have updated the answer a bit in light of this. If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.